# Android notofication and activity order

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

I have an app with two activity A and B.
The activity A (main activity) list users.
The activity B show selected user data.

from firebase notofication service if user data changed i get notofication.
i click the notofication and open activity B

my scenerio when notofication click

if my app running 
    open activity B show user data from notification
    and back pressed close B and open A
if my app running background
    open activity B show user data from notification
    and back pressed close B and open A
if my app not running
    open activity B show user data from notification
    and back pressed close B and open A

how to solve this

Comment: You will have to create backstack to achieve this behaviour. Consider the scenario where your app is killed and then you get the push notification. On click it will open Activity B but on back press, it will get out of the app as there's only one activity in the stack. Please refer https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Add `launchMode` in your Actvity B in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
   android:launchMode="singleTask"
```